# Python module random

Tags: python, random

I want to work module random,choice in python
so i entered code written the book
but it dosent work
i want see print random number

[image]
i don't know why it dosen't work
i entered as it is saw book
and i dont enter any ohter code

i am beginner python,english
sorry

Comment: written in which book?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass in a list (`[]`) rather than a set (`{}`) for [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) function as the argument requirement:

```
random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```